# how to improve code quality (mostly duplicates)

Tags: java

I have a set of variables that was passed in by a mega method in an ancient legacy code.....

```
public List<type> check (String required, String sales, String report,
 Long passId, Long seatId, String capName, String vCapName, 
 String attName, Long vid) {

        if(required != null) {
            goodA = method(required);
            goodB = methodTwo(required);
            goodC = methodThree(required);
        }
        if(sales != null) {
            goodA = method(sales);
            goodB = methodTwo(sales);
            goodC = methodThree(sales);
        }
        if(report != null) {
            goodA = method(report);
            goodB = methodTwo(report);
            goodC = methodThree(report);
        if(passId != null)
        ... you got the point....


}
```

The variables that passed into check can only be 1 valid value all other variables will become null.
For example 
check("Yes",null,null,null,null,null...)
or 
check(null,null,null,13212L,null,null,null,null)

right now I am trying to rewrite this into something less repetitive and clean I was wondering if anyone can provide some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Have `check` accept only a single value?

Comment: but it has different types. not just string but long as well

Comment: Are there overloads of `method` etc for `Long` as well as `String`?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the `String` values, since the value is passed to the methods and the only difference seems to be the fact that you're doing a `null` check, it might be better to simply accept a single `String` parameter

Comment: At the very least, you could collapse the branches for `required`, `sales`, `report` etc by using a method like `Objects.firstNonNull` to get the first one which isn't null, and then call `method`, `methodTwo`, `methodThree` etc on that instance.

Comment: the thing is that inside of the check those method( -- ) are dao classes. so If we make it into a single string how do I categorize them like which dao to pass to

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying that it's not the same `method`, `methodTwo`, `methodThree` in each of the conditionals?

Comment: no, all the method is the same method, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
List<Object> items = Lists.newArrayList(required, sales, report,
 capName, vCapName, attName);

for(Object item : items) {
    if(item != null){
        methodOne(item);
        methodTwo(item);    
        methodThree(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about Long type?

Comment: Changed the list to "Object" instead of "String" which is the base type of both String and Long (and everything else in Java) so that you can add all your fields in one list